# adding a keyword argument to an overridden method and using **kwarg

Tags: python

I am subclassing an object in order to override a method that I want to add some functionality to. I don't want to completely replace it or add a differently named method but remain compatible to the superclasses method by just adding an optional argument to the method.
Is it possible to work with `*args` and `**kwargs` to pass through all arguments to the superclass and still add an optional argument with a default?
I intuitively came up with the following but it doesn't work:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2, argopt1="bar"):
        print arg1, arg2, argopt1

class B(A):
    def foo(self, *args, argopt2="foo", **kwargs):
        print argopt2
        A.foo(self, *args, **kwargs)


b = B()
b.foo("a", "b", argopt2="foo")
```

Of course I can get it to work when I explicitly add all the arguments of the method of the superclass:

```
class B(A):
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2, argopt1="foo", argopt2="bar"):
        print argopt2
        A.foo(self, arg1, arg2, argopt1=argopt1)
```

What's the right way to do this, do I have to know and explicitly state all of the overridden methods arguments?

Answer (score 14):

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2, argopt1="bar"):
        print arg1, arg2, argopt1

class B(A):
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        argopt2 = kwargs.get('argopt2', default_for_argopt2)
        # remove the extra arg so the base class doesn't complain. 
        del kwargs['argopt2']
        print argopt2
        A.foo(self, *args, **kwargs)


b = B()
b.foo("a", "b", argopt2="foo")
```

Comment: You can use pop instead of get + del.

Comment: I always forget about dict.pop!

Comment: Your example fails with `KeyError` when `argopt2` is not passed. Using `kwargs.pop('argopt2', default_for_argopt2)` is the simplest way to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

> What's the right way to do this, do I
>   have to know and explicitly state all
>   of the overridden methods arguments?

If you want to cover all cases (rather than just rely on the caller to always do things your way, e.g., always call you only with the extra argument passed by-name, never by position) you do have to code (or dynamically discover) a lot of knowledge about the signature of the method you're overriding -- hardly surprising: inheritance is a strong form of coupling, and overriding methods is one way that coupling presents itself.

You *could* dynamically discover the superclass's method arguments via [inspect.getargspec](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.getargspec), in order to make sure you call it properly... but this introspection technique can get tricky if **two** classes are trying to do exactly the same thing (once you know your superclass's method accepts `*a` and/or `**kw` you can do little more than pass all the relevant arguments upwards and hope, with fingers crossed, that the upstream method chain eventually does proper housecleaning before calling a version that's not quite so tolerant).

Such prices may be worth paying when you're designing a wrapper that's meant to be applied dynamically to callables with a wide variety of signatures (especially since in a decorator setting you can arrange to pay the hefty cost of introspection just once per function you're decorating, not every time the resulting wrapper is called). It seems unlikely to be a worthwhile technique in a case such as yours, where you'd better know what you're subclassing (subclassing is strong coupling: doing it blindly is definitely not advisable!), and so you might as well spell out the arguments explicitly.

Yes, if the superclass's code changes drastically (e.g., by altering method signatures), you'll have to revise the subclass as well -- that's (part of) the price of inheritance. The overall price's hefty enough that the new [Go](http://golang.org/) programming language does totally without it -- *forcing* you to apply the [Gang of 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern)'s excellent advice to [prefer composition over inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/steverowe/archive/2008/04/28/prefer-composition-over-inheritance.aspx). In Python complete abstinence from inheritance would just be impractical, but using it soberly and in moderation (and accepting the price you'll pay in terms of coupling when you do) remains advisable.

Comment: +1 for caveats on signature changes. But I think there is an exception: it's OK to change the signature of constructor. And the problem described in the question is applicable to constructor too.

Comment: The link to "prefer composition over inheritance" is dead and I couldn't find the article - do you have an updated link?

Answer (score 2):

When subclassing and overriding methods, one must always decide if using `super()` is a good idea, and [this page](http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/) is good for that.

I'm *not* saying that `super()` should be avoided, like the article author may be: I'm saying that `super()` has some very important prerequisits that must be followed if you don't want `super()` to come back and bite you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using different approach:

```py
def base_func(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    pass

def func(arg1, arg2 = None, **kwargs):
    kwargs["arg1"] = kwargs.get("arg1", arg1)
    kwargs["arg2"] = kwargs.get("arg2", arg2)
    kwargs["arg3"] = kwargs.get("arg3", "my_default_value")
    base_func(**kwargs)
```

This way I'm sure that:

- each argument will appear only once when passing arguments to base_func
- Value defined in "my_default_value" will not override anything already given in **kwargs,
- I will explicitly expose arg1 and arg2, which allows me to add some extra documentation, default values or limitations.

I also like the idea with .pop() proposed by [Denis Otkidach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168352/denis-otkidach).